# CKFinder connector.php error 500

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I have a website built with CodeIgniter which, for the admin area, is using CKEditor and CKFinder to write posts for the news section.

The CKFinder image uploader was working with no problems, but two days ago I had to move the files on another server. Till then I get the 500 error when trying to upload images.

Behavior:
I open the Upload image modal window. I browse and select an image and when I click the Send to server button I get a 404 error message (the custom 404 page of CodeIgniter). In firebug it shows that there is a 500 internal server error.

File path is plugins/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php and it exists on the server.

Comment: After reading some articles on the internet about my problem I think that I may found out what can cause it. It's probably the actived mod_security2 of my apache that blocks the uploading. Does anyone has any idea how can I stop this module blocking my file uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out the problem was a file permission issue. The folder in which I have to save the images had 777 permission (and for the old server was the good one) and it needed 755 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue i have to add :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in the followings files: config.php and ckfinder.php in the root of the directory ckfinder.